# Plugin Zonal Statistics not available in 3.30 anymore

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, zonal-statistics

I would like to use the Plugin "Zonal Statistics" in 3.30 Version but can`t find it. I also downloaded it manually, but QGIS says "This plugin is incompatible with this version of QGIS". Is there another PLugin similar to Zonal Statistics?

Comment: Can you use the built in zonal statistics? https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgiszonalstatisticsfb

Comment: This plugin doesn't not exist for a few years already I think. You should use the "Processing toolbox" instead, as described with the comment above.